# How to query Azure capabilities API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

At this microsoft documentation address

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases

I found the following note in many parameters:

> To see possible values, query the capabilities API.

Unfortunately it's not explained how to query "the capabilities API"

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/capabilities/listbylocation).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/{locationId}/capabilities?api-version=2014-04-01
```

You could call the api with Power Shell(just an example, you also could use other language to call the API).

```
##get token
$TENANTID=""
$APPID=""
$PASSWORD=""
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

##set subscriptionId 
$subscriptionId=""

$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'host'="management.azure.com"
    'contentype'='application/json'
}
$url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/eastus/capabilities?api-version=2014-04-01"

Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url  -Headers $Headers -Method GET
```